# How to normalize the distance between two distributions

Tags: machine-learning, probability, distributions, normalization, standardization

I'm creating a distance metric that is composed out of multiple pairwise feature distances.

The distance metric will be used in a clustering algorithm for a computer security problem, more specifically the clustering algorithm will group together related "malicious instances". Our hypothesis is that malicious instances will share similar characteristics (=features), as opposed to benign instances (they are more diverse), hence the distance between a malicious and benign instance will be greater.

To see whether a particular feature results in a close distance between *two malicious instances* and a larger distance between *a malicious and a benign instance*, I plotted the density of the **distances to the closest malicious instance** for malicious instances (green) and benign instance (red). As you can see, the distance to the closest malicious instance is generally less (or even zero) for malicious instances.

[image: A]

[image: B]

[image: C]

Initially, I want each of these pairwise feature distances to have an equal impact/weight on the total distance (=sum). I believe when I would simply add up these three different pairwise distances, I would loose a lot of the discriminating impact of the features whose distance between the two distributions is smaller (e.g. in the second graph). In other words, I think the total distance would benefit from spreading out the "two peaks/distributions" as far as possible, making all graphs center/align at 0.5. When the impact of all features is equal, I then plan to assign weights to the most discriminating ones.

Unfortunately, I lack the statistical knowledge to confirm whether this is makes sense, and which techniques could be used to accomplish this. Any insights?

Comment: I think you need to give us more details about what you are doing here including: what is distance for you, what is a feature, what total distance means, and so on.

Comment: @mdewey, You're right! I added some more context and details. Thanks.